Using sqrt function within a while loop, don't understand it
I'm currently going through "C++ Without Fear, Third Edition". I'm a little confused with this block of code, I understand how the if statement is used to find out if n is divisible by i. I just don't understand what is the point of the while loop.
Surely, you could just write the code without it and if the if loop comes back with a remainder then it will be a prime number, otherwise it will not be a prime number.
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n = 0; // Number to test for prime-ness
    int i = 2; // Loop counter
    bool is_prime = true;   // Boolean flag...
                            // Assume true for now

    // Get a number from the keyboard
    cout << "Enter a number and press ENTER: ";
    cin >> n;

    // Test for prime by checking for divisibility
    // by all whole numbers from 2 to sqrt(n).

    while (i <= sqrt(n)){
        if (n % i == 0) {       // If i divides n,
            is_prime = false;   // n is not prime
            break;              // BREAK OUT OF LOOP NOW!
        }
        ++i;                    // Add 1 to i.
    }

    // Print results

    if (is_prime) {
        cout << "Number is prime." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Number is not prime." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

I don't understand it, please help me.

Do you understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division?

Think about the math. Factors come in pairs. If you always look at the smaller factor of the pair, what's the largest it can be?  If you don't find a factor up to that limit, what can you conclude?

You could write the code without  the square root, and it would still work, but be much much slower in certain cases. Try to work out why.

You need to divide n by 2, 3, 4, 5,..... While loop is an iteration process that enables you do do exactly that. Without it, then you will just be dividing n by 2 and thats it. But just because a number is not divisible by 2 does not mean its prime. If you are talking about the sqrt, note that a number 12 for example will have the factors 2x6, 3x4. If I have checked for 2, there is no need of checking for 6. If I have checked for 3, there is no need of checking for 4. thus to save time, we check upto the sqrt of n.

If you don't like sqrt or don't want to use it, replace loop condition with while (i*i < n)

^ Often performance benefits as well. i*i is a lot cheaper than computing the square root of n

On a side note: n never changes, so sqrt(n) never changes, so calling it on every loop iteration is redundant and inefficient.  You should call sqrt(n) one time and save the result in a variable, and then have the loop use that variable instead, eg: int s = sqrt(n); while (i <= s){ ... }.

It is usually inadvisable to use a floating point function (like sqrt()) when doing calculations that work with integral values, and give an integral result.   Floating point introduces imprecision, which can result either inprecise results or in loops behaving differently than intended (e.g. iterating more or less times that would be expected mathematically).    A quick google search would turn up an "integer square root" (function that produces the largest integer value that doesn't exceed the mathematical square root, without using floating point at all)

This is crucial for efficiently checking.
The while loop iterates through potential divisors of n starting from 2 up to sqrt(n). This is an efficient way to test for primality because:

Instead of checking all numbers from 2 to n-1, checking up to sqrt(n) reduces the number of iterations; if a number n has a divisor larger than sqr(n), the corresponding co-divisor must be smaller than sqr(n).

By checking all possible divisors up to sqrt(n), you ensure that if n is composite, you will find a divisor within this range, and if no divisors are found then n is prime.


If you remove the while loop and just use an if statement, you would need to explicitly list all potential divisors, which is impractical and inefficient. The while loop provides a systematic way to check all necessary divisors up to sqrt(n).

I just realised I was being stupid… thank you very much
